# dev.of_node is always NULL in probe function of platform_driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, device-tree

I am facing some issues in device driver and device tree binding. The following is my device tree:

```
my_device {
    compatible = "my_driver";
    status = "okay";
};
```

And the driver source code is:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/err.h>
#include <linux/of.h>
#include <linux/of_device.h>


static int my_driver_platform_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
        return 0;
}
  
static int my_driver_platform_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{   
    const char* status_prop = NULL;
    if (pdev->dev.of_node == NULL) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "my_driver_platform_probe: Can't find compatible node in device tree\n");
        return -ENOENT;
    }

    status_prop = of_get_property(pdev->dev.of_node, "status", NULL);
    if(status_prop)
        printk(KERN_INFO "my_driver_platform_probe : status prop %s\n", status_prop);

    return 0;
}


static struct of_device_id my_driver_of_match[] = {
        { .compatible = "my_driver"},
        {}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, my_driver_of_match);  
  

static struct platform_driver cdottdc_platform_driver = {
        .driver = {
                .name = "my_driver",
                //.name = MODULE_NAME,
                .owner = THIS_MODULE,
                .of_match_table = my_driver_of_match,
        },
        .probe = my_driver_platform_probe,
        .remove = my_driver_platform_remove,
};

static void __exit mymodule_exit(void)
{
        platform_driver_unregister(&cdottdc_platform_driver);
    printk(KERN_INFO "mymodule_exit : unregistered platform driver\n");
}
  
static int __init mymodule_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "mymodule_init : registering platform driver\n");  
        return platform_driver_register(&cdottdc_platform_driver);
}

module_init(mymodule_init);
module_exit(mymodule_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Sample driver");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Prasanta");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");
```

The the following print is got during inserting module:

```
root@petalinux:~# insmod ./my_driver.ko 
[  149.309748] my_driver: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  149.316086] mymodule_init : registering platform driver
[  149.321529] my_driver_platform_probe: Can't find compatible node in device tree
[  149.328844] my_driver: probe of my_device failed with error -2
```

The device already there in the device tree which is confirmed by the following commands:

```
root@petalinux:~# ls /proc/device-tree/my_device/ -l                                                                                      
total 0
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            10 Aug 13 05:17 compatible
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            10 Aug 13 05:17 name
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             5 Aug 13 05:17 status
root@petalinux:~# cat  /proc/device-tree/my_device/status 
okayroot@petalinux:~# cat  /proc/device-tree/my_device/compatible 
my_driverroot@petalinux:~# cat  /proc/device-tree/my_device/name 
my_deviceroot@petalinux:~#
```

So my questions are:

1. Why the pdev->dev.of_node is NULL in my_driver_platform_probe call?
2. Did I miss something in device-tree or the driver?

Comment: You got it enumerated by name. Try to change compatible to something like _mycompany,mydev_  in the DTS and driver (in two locations).

Comment: I have updated the compatible in the device tree and  my_driver_of_match variable in the driver to `compatible = "mycompany,mydev"`. But still the of_node is NULL during probing.

Comment: According to in-kernel unit tests I see for OF you probably need to have a namespace for all DT, something like https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/of/unittest-data/tests-match.dtsi.

Comment: I guess the structure is only for matching the DT with driver. Can't we say that driver is correctly matched with device node as the driver probe function is being executed?

Comment: Yes, you have a match, but I asked you explicitly to change compatible that it will be different to the driver name. In that case you will have a match by compatible. Also you have to read Open Firmware specification to understand the scope of the device node you are trying to use. In last you might have found a subtle bug in the OF code.

Comment: I tried with different compatible field as you suggested without any success. I don't think it's kernel bug. I lot of platform drivers uses of_node structure in their probe function. I must have missed something. I was planning to check with different kernel version if the problem persists.

Comment: Which function of kernel fills of_node structure before calling probe?

Answer (score 0):

I found a dirty fix :

```
if (pdev->dev.of_node == NULL) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "my_driver_platform_probe: Can't find compatible node in device tree. Retrying\n"); 
    pdev->dev.of_node  = of_find_node_by_name(NULL, "mydevice");        
}
```

However this doesn't answer my actual question.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue.
because the running linux kernel is different with the kernel module build environment.
I fix this issue by recompiling the linux kernel and kernel module with the same code base.

Comment: This can be applicable for my case as well. I will try recompiling kernel in same build environment and let you know. Thanks for pointing out.